# Debug shows there is no unexpected character, but exception shows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

I have an object that I am sending to my server from my client on Unity. The server is able to reassemble the data into it's natural type and read from the properties.

**Client MessagaData**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
[Serializable]
public class MessagaData
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public string dataString { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Server MessagaData**

```
using System;



namespace Server
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MessagaData
    {
        public int type { get; set; }
        public string dataString { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When the user presses the login button it will first create a MessagaData object and assign it some properties.

```
public void sendLoginDetails()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (username.text))
        return;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (password.text))
        return;
    MessagaData md = new MessagaData ();
    md.type = 1;
    md.User = username.text;
    md.Password = password.text;
    Client.Send (md);
}
```

Then the Static function is called: where md is passed.

```
static public void Send(MessagaData msgData)
{
    if (singleton.client == null)
        return;

    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgData);
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    NetworkStream ns = singleton.client.GetStream ();
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (output);
    ns.Write (data, 0, data.Length);
    ns.Flush ();
    ReadThis ();

}
```

After sending the code the object, this function, ReadMe is invoked, where the error is obtained;

> {"type":1,"dataString":null,"User":null,"Password":null}

Tracking the debugger on the code

```
              throw CreateJsonReaderException("After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {0}. Line {1}, position {2}.", currentChar, _currentLineNumber, _currentLinePosition);
```

it appears that what I receive from the server is something I Json canto read.

**The Server:**

```
private void myMethod(object obj)
{
    int type = (int)obj;
    MessagaData msgData = new MessagaData();
    msgData.type = type;
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgData);
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(output);
    ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    ns.Flush();
}
```

Why does my client crash when a MessagaData is trying to be built?

EDIT -- 01/03/2016

1) What does your ReadMe() method look like?

```
    public static void ReadThis()
{

    if (singleton.client == null)
    return;
    NetworkStream ns = singleton.client.GetStream ();
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    ns.Read (data, 0, data.Length);
    string output = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

    Debug.LogWarning (output);
```

> ```
>   MessagaData md = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessagaData>(output); //i am the error
> ```

```
    switch(md.type)
    {
    case 1:
        Debug.LogWarning ("Success");
        break;

    case 2:
        Debug.LogWarning ("Failed");
        //Thread.Sleep (500);
        break;
    }
}
```

Since it's the server where the exception is thrown, can you share that code?

The exception is thrown in the client side of the code, in the `ReadMe()` method

2) Can you give the full ToString() output of the exception including the message and traceback? It would be helpful to know the current character, line number, and line position, and stack trace inside Json.NET.

This is on the client;

```
        try {
        MessagaData md = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessagaData> (output);
        switch(md.type)
        {
        case 1:
            Debug.LogWarning ("Success");
            break;

        case 2:
            Debug.LogWarning ("Failed");
            //Thread.Sleep (500);
            break;
        }
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        Debug.Log (ex.ToString ());
    }
```

Debug shows:

```
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Client:ReadThis() (at Assets/Scripts/Client.cs:73)
Client:Send(MessagaData) (at Assets/Scripts/Client.cs:45)
SendLoginInformation:sendLoginDetails() (at Assets/Scripts/SendLoginInformation.cs:26)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

3) Is the server using unity3d also, or using Microsoft .Net?
The server is C# Microsoft .NET If you like I can zip it and upload it since it is a very small program

To DBC.

Comment: 1) What does your `ReadMe()` method look like?  Since it's the server where the exception is thrown, can you share that code?  2) Can you give the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message and traceback?  It would be helpful to know the current character, line number, and line position, and stack trace inside Json.NET.  3) Is the server using unity3d also, or using Microsoft .Net?

Comment: Firstly, don't use [`Encoding.ASCII`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It strips non-7-bit characters and replaces them with a fallback.  Secondly, you may need to use message framing along the lines of [Receiving data from a network stream](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27946/) or http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html, but I cannot say for sure without a full [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the receiving server code.

Comment: @dbc sorry, i slept for 14 hours. Now I can get back to you. Yes, should I use little/big endian? I thought my messagaData object was a "message frame?"  I have updated code.